# Shared Google Map Between All Users on Mobile

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, mobile

I was trying to work on creating a shared map for all users by using the Google Maps API. I would like User A to be able to see User B on the map, assuming User B is sharing his location. How can this be accomplished using Google Maps API on Android or iOS? This would basically resemble the Uber application where the costumers can see the drivers on the map.

Comment: so what have you done so far aside from creating this post?

Comment: I've gone through a tutorial to set up the Google Maps on iOS so far, but haven't figured out how I can make the users show up to each other. I've tried searching online but I haven't come up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this functionality isn't really available through the `API`. What you could do is check if the user's location is available for sharing. Then using your own backend, most likely a `MBaaS`, share the location data with people they allowed access to their location. Then you could just draw a marker on the map representing the user